# JSoup wrap a list of elements

Tags: jsoup

how can i wrap the complete content of body into a seperate `<div>`?

I cant just simply use `body.wrap("div")` - it would wrap the body and not the body's content.

I also cant use `body.text().wrap()`.

What's the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
// Before: <body><span>example</span></body>
// After: <div><span>example</span></div>

String html = "<body><span>example</span></body>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element body = doc.body();

if (body != null)
    body.tagName("div");

System.out.println(doc.html());
```